# Is it possible to use X-AppEngine-Country within an application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, geolocation

When serving a request, GAE automatically inserts response header `X-AppEngine-Country` set to a value indicating the country from which the request was emitted. However, before GAE issues the response, I’d like to be able to use this value in a snippet of mine.

I wrote this code:

```py
class TestPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        country = self.response.headers["X-AppEngine-Country"]
        self.response.out.write("<pre>country %s </pre>" % country)
```

But opening the page results in a crash:

```
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1/webob/headers.py", line 16, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'x-appengine-country'
```

Is there any ways to use this value within the application?

Comment: Why do you think that the response should have a country code? Why do you need to have a country code in the response? \

Comment: @ShayErlichmen I think you missed the point. The response HAS a country code because Google App Engine inserts it. [more here](http://www.rominirani.com/2011/07/11/x-appengine-country-http-header-google-app-engine/)

Comment: repose is what goes OUT the request is what comes IN, I think that you mixed up response and request

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to get the headers of the response (which you're about to make), rather than the headers of the request. Try this instead.

```
country = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Country')
```

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_headers

> The request headers, a dictionary-like object. Keys are case-insensitive.