# Is there a way to handle requests with locale-dependant wsgi handlers?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, wsgi, webapp2

Is there a way to handle requests from different geographic locations with a different WSGI handler? Specifically I want to allow all requests from one local (US) and redirect all others to a holding page i.e. something like

```
application_us = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', MainHandler)
    ], debug=DEBUG)

application_elsewhere = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', HoldingPageHandler)
    ], debug=DEBUG)
```

I'm aware of X-AppEngine-Country however I'm not quite sure how to put it to use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, building the answer by Sebastian Kreft I figured it's probably easiest to throw this into a base handler of which every other handler is a subclass as follows.

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        country = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Country')
        if not country == "US" and not country == "" and not country == None: # The last two handle local development
            self.redirect('international_holding_page')
            logging.info(country)
```

This is more in keeping with DRY though I'm not certain it's the most efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to have only one app and in the handler redirect the user to a HoldingPageHandler if the country is not supported.

See [Is it possible to use X-AppEngine-Country within an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500604/is-it-possible-to-use-x-appengine-country-within-an-application).  There they explain how to get the country

```
country = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Country')
```

So your handler would be something like this

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    country = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Country')
      if country != "US":
        self.redirect_to('hold') #assuming you have a route to hold
      # your logic
```

Comment: This is one way to do it, but what the OP is asking about is also a perfectly legitimate way to handle things. Further, putting this in every handler is a seriously suboptimal way to do it.